# Multingual Android app in kotlin giving this message : System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

Tags: java, android, kotlin

i was trying to make a multilingual app in android following this tutorial :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywF-ySiBAsc

i'm using kotlin in developing the app and im facing some error i can't handle it so far.

here's the app_intro Activity:

```
package com.xr.mapbased
import android.content.Context
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyContextWrapper
import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyConfig
import android.content.DialogInterface
import android.media.VolumeShaper
import com.google.android.gms.stats.WakeLock
import java.util.*
import android.content.res.Configuration
import android.content.res.Resources
import android.preference.PreferenceManager
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import com.climaxwares.mapbased.helper.LocaleHelper


class app_intro : AppCompatActivity() {

var btnSingIn: Button? = null
var btnRegister:Button? = null
var btnChangeLang:TextView? = null
var LocaleAttach:   LocaleHelper? = null

override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleAttach?.onAttach(newBase,"en"))
}
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
            .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Roboto-medium.ttf")
            .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
            .build()
    )
    val getLang = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(baseContext)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_intro)
    btnRegister = findViewById(R.id.RegisterBtn) as Button
    btnSingIn = findViewById(R.id.SignInBtn) as Button
    btnChangeLang = findViewById(R.id.change_lang) as TextView

    val Language: String = getLang.getString("language","ar")
    if(Language == null)
        getLang.edit().putString("language","en")

    updateView("ar")


}

private fun updateView(Language: String) {
    val context: Context = LocaleAttach!!.setLocale(this,Language)
    val resources: Resources = context.getResources();

    btnSingIn!!.text = resources.getString(R.string.sign_in)
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean{
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.lang_menu,menu)
    return true
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem?): Boolean {
    val getLang = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(baseContext)
    if(menuItem!!.getItemId() == R.id.language_en){
        getLang.edit().putString("language","en")
        updateView("en")
    }


    if(menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.language_ar){
        getLang.edit().putString("language","ar")
        updateView("ar")
    }
    return true
}
}
```

and im getting these errors:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.climaxwares.mapbased, PID: 10816
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.climaxwares.mapbased/com.climaxwares.mapbased.app_intro}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
>                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
>                         at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:4595)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:211)
>                         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.(PhoneWindow.java:289)
>                         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.Policy.makeNewWindow(Policy.java:61)
>                         at com.android.internal.policy.PolicyManager.makeNewWindow(PolicyManager.java:57)
>                         at android.app.Activity.attach(Activity.java:5253)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645) 
>                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I will be here for further questions, thank you in advanced :)

Answer (score 0):

we don’t have static methods in Kotlin?!

that was the problem, it was in the adapter file itself not in the MainActivity.

so when i was trying to call the class it gave me the above error.
i've found this tutorial very useful.

https://android.jlelse.eu/daily-kotlin-static-methods-9330552cde8a

although i made the adapter file in Java was way more direct in development.

here's the adapter code:

```
package com.xr.mapbased.helper;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import java.util.*;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.os.Build;

import com.google.android.gms.stats.WakeLock;

import java.util.Locale;


public class LocaleJ {
private static final String SELECTED_LANGUAGE = "Locale.Helper.Selected.Language";
public static Context onAttach(Context context){
    String lang = getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
    return setLocale(context,lang);
}

public static Context onAttach(Context context,String defaultLanguage){
    String lang = getPersistedData(context,defaultLanguage);
    return setLocale(context,lang);
}

private static String getPersistedData(Context context, String lang) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return preferences.getString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE,lang);
}

private static void persist(Context context, String language) {
    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

    editor.putString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, language);
    editor.apply();
}

public static Context setLocale(Context context, String lang) {
    persist(context,lang);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        return updateResources(context,lang);

    return updateResourcesLegacy(context,lang);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
private static Context updateResources(Context context, String lang) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    config.setLocale(locale);
    config.setLayoutDirection(locale);

    return context.createConfigurationContext(config);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private static Context updateResourcesLegacy(Context context, String lang) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    Configuration config = resources.getConfiguration();
    config.locale = locale;

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
        config.setLayoutDirection(locale);

    resources.updateConfiguration(config,resources.getDisplayMetrics());
    return context;
}
```

}